# 'Unable to determine Swift version for the following pod" - Error

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install `pod 'SVProgressHUD'` cocoa pod, but it is giving following error while installing pod file.

```
[!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods:

- `HexColors` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`FaveoHelpdeskPro_ObjC`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.
```

[image: Erro Screenshot]

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute.

Answer (score 82):

Try to set the Swift version by including

`ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5'` at the top of your Podfile.

Comment: This solved the original problem however the problem is not solved completely. Now I am getting this error: `fatal error: 'hexcolor/hexcolor-Swift.h' file not found`

Comment: @Shajeel Afazl me too!

Answer (score 11):

It's because your project is very old and never set Swift version in the project.
Try to create one new swift file in the project. Xcode will automatically set Swift version in project build settings. Then you can `pod install` again and it will be solved.

Comment: The top voted solution created other bugs .. this one fixed the SWIFT_VERSION issue for stripe-react-native sdk with no following issues

Comment: Nice, it works.