# Cocoapods not fully adding new pod/dependency to existing workspace project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Noob with cocoapods but somewhat experienced coder.  Have existing cocoapods project that I needed to add a pod (PersonalizedAdConsent) to.  Installed cocoapods with 
`sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`
because it wouldn't install otherwise
v 1.8.4.  Then cd to project dir, ran pod install and get...
[terminal image snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5e3r.jpg)

Pod was copied to project directory when checked, but open in Xcode and Pods directory does not update to include new pod in project structure.  Also, cannot import new pod in code, get cannot find header.  It's like it doesn't exist, although I know it is there.  Am I doing something wrong?

Steps I've taken while trying to troubleshoot...

1. pod deintegrate and readd all pods, then all the pods get deleted,
   then copied back from repo and now all headers can't be found.
2. searched google because I assumed I must be doing something wrong, probably still true although I could not find an answer
3. uninstall cocoapods and reinstall, hasn't worked
4. downgrade to 1.7.5, hasn't worked
5. remove all traces of cocoapods from computer and reinstall (maybe I should have restarted my mac when I tried this but I did not)

macOS 10.14.6, default ruby version, Xcode 11.2.1, iterm, not sure if it makes a difference but project also contains lock file prior to trying to add new pod

Comment: try running ```pod repo update``` then  ```pod install```

Comment: Got Updating spec repo 'trunk' message then prompt, problem persists

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784154/4422582

Comment: Eugene's answer worked, thank you sir!  It seems the error on a different pod was stopping the full installation of any new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by stating swift version as per Eugene's comment above.

Eugene said
Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784154/4422582

For quick reference, it says to add

ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5' at the top of your Podfile.